# Python and Qt5 - importing the module and using it

Tags: python, pyqt5

Have problems with python and the PyQt5 package. When writing the most basic code as`from PyQt5 import QtGui`, Python doesn't throw a fit.

When I try to access any funktion from QtGui to make some widgets, I just get a fault report stating:
"AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication".

I'm not doing anything serious except trying to learn a new gui framework for Python (and of course reads up on the documentation at the same time).

Any suggestions about where to start? Have installed all modules that pyqt5 demands

Comment: QApplication was in QtGui for Qt4, now it's in PyQt5.QtWidgets.

Comment: thanks for the info